# Why '1+log slicing condition' and 'Gamma Driver Shift Condition' were successful in black hole simulations?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, gravitational-waves

**The 1+log slicing and Gamma driver shift conditions are**

[image]

**I want to know if there is a specific reason why these conditions were used most for Black Hole simulations in Numerical Relativty.
And how they arrived at these equations at first place.**